# A Pythonic way to get unique values in a Pandas data frame column based on multiple filtering criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the unique values in a particular column in a Pandas data frame based on multiple filtering criteria.  Here is some toy code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['<null', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'],
                          'Color':['Purple', '<null>', '<null>', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Green', 'Black', 'White', 'Gold', 'Tan']})
```

I'm trying to get a list of the unique values of the `Color` column assuming:

a) a **non-null value** in the `Color` column, and

b) a value of 'Audi' in the `Manufacturer` column

Is there a Pythonic way that doesn't require me to 'pre-process' the data by taking a subset of the data frame, as such:

```
df_1 = df[(df['Color'] != '<null>') & (df['Manufacturer'] == 'Audi')]
df_1['Color'].unique()

array(['Blue', 'Green', 'Black', 'White'], dtype=object)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subset the dataframe with required conditions. There's no escaping that.

You can always write your code in 1-line, like this:

```
df[(df['Color'] != '<null>') & (df['Manufacturer'].eq('Audi'))]['Color'].unique()
```

Also, it's nice to represent a `null` value in dataframe with `numpy.nan`. Your `df` would be this:

```
In [86]: import numpy as np 
In [81]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':[np.nan, 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'], 
    ...:                           'Color':['Purple', np.nan, np.nan, 'Blue', 'Green', 'Green', 'Black', 'White', 'Gold', 'Tan']})
```

Then you can use [`df.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) , which are a bit more pythonic:

```
In [85]: df[df.Color.notna() & df.Manufacturer.eq('Audi')]['Color'].unique() 
Out[85]: array(['Blue', 'Green', 'Black', 'White'], dtype=object)
```

### After OP's comment:

Can specify multiple values using `isin`:

```
df[(df['Color'] != '<null>') & (df['Manufacturer'].isin(['Audi', 'Mercedes']))]['Color'].unique()
```

Comment: Thank works perfectly, thank you.  I was not aware of .eq().

Comment: Is there a way to specify multiple `Manufacturer` values?  For example, how can we specify 'Audi' *and* 'Mercedes'?